# C Structure Padding. Nested Structures

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct, padding

```
struct Y{
  int int_one;
  int int_two;
  void * pointer;
}

struct X{
    char char_one;
    char char_two;
    struct Y y_structures[20];
 }
```

the padding is different on 32 and 64 bit machines. I don't know why. 
As far as I know the padding should be as follows :

```
 0x0 char_one <br>
 0x1 char_two <br>
 0x4 y_structures[0].int_one <br>
 0x8 y_structures[0].int_two <br>
 0x12 y_structure[0].pointer <br>
```

the structure on 32 bit is similar as mentioned above but on 64 bit machine the difference between addresses of `char_two` and `y_structures[0].int_one` is 7 bytes. I think that it should be 3 bytes because the type to be aligned after `char_two` is an int of the `y_structures[0]` and it's size is 4 on both architectures. Kindly help

Comment: Just curious, what tool are you using to detect padding amount?

Comment: The real question is: why do you care? If you just want to learn, fine. But if you want to write portable code, don't write a code that relies on specific padding.

Comment: There are semicolons missing after the struct definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the int, it's the pointer. pointer have a size of 8 bytes on 64bit machines, therefore they must start at a memory address mod 8.

```
0x0 char_one
0x1 char_two
0x8 y_structures[0].int_one
0x12 y_structures[0].int_two
0x16 y_structure[0].pointer
0x24 y_structures[1].int_one
0x28 y_structures[1].int_two
0x32 y_structure[1].pointer
...
```

so there must be 6 padding bytes. This is not necessary on 32 bit machines, because there pointer only have 4 byte.

Comment: You may be correct on this case, do not assume that values are always 8 for 64bit and 4 for 32bit. C standard gives no such restriction, it comes from the design of the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between 32/64 bit systems: 32-bit systems will still align 8-byte variables to 32-bit boundaries. 64-bit systems will align long int and double to 8-byte boundaries.

Comment: no, 8byte variables will also align on multiples of 8 on 32bit machines, see: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/ question number 6

Comment: Ravi is right. The data types fpos_t, off_t, and long long are exceptions to the natural alignment rules in 32-bit executables. Though they are all 8-byte (64-bit) types, they are aligned on 4-byte (32-bit) boundaries. Same goes for doubles, check check System V x86 ABI. (p28: Figure 3-1): http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf

Comment: The distinction only applies to 32-bit vs 64-bit ABIs for the Intel platforms.  On many other types of hardware, `double` is an 8-byte quantity that must be aligned to an 8-byte boundary regardless of whether the compilation is for 32-bit or 64-bit on that platform.  The Intel behaviour is anomalous across the spectrum of CPU types.

Answer (score -1):

Also you have to keep in mind that some architectures require data alignment (can access data only if the address is aligned). It can be 32bit architecture, you can use 4 char elements and structure size to be 16 bytes of size for example.